# How to get Time difference Between Datetime, Date and Time columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have table called Data_Details and the data looks like:

```
DateTimeClosed            Datesub            TimeSub
6/20/2011 18:00           5/16/2011          17:13:17
6/20/2011 18:00           5/18/2011          13:45:17
6/1/2011 19:00            5/24/2011          8:30:12
```

I am trying to get the difference between closed date and sub date in mins.

I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT  convert(int,convert(Datetime,[DateTimeClosed])-
(convert(Datetime,[Datesub])+convert(datetime,[TimeSub])))*24*60 
FROM dbo.Data_details
```

It is giving me following error:

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please give us your table structure (data types of the columns)

Comment: @Lamak all the columns are of   [varchar] (50) datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns time difference in seconds:

```
select datediff(SECOND,'5/16/2011'+' '+'17:13:17','6/20/2011 18:00')
```

Sample script:

```
declare @test as table
(
date1 datetime,
date2 date,
date3 time
)
insert into @test 
values
('6/20/2011 18:00'         ,  '5/16/2011'        ,  '17:13:17')
select Datediff(second,cast (date2 as varchar)+' '+ cast(date3 as varchar),date1) from @test
```

**UPDATE**- Using varchars now that OP clarified that they are all varchars:

```
declare @test as table
(
date1 varchar(50),
date2 varchar(50),
date3 varchar(50)
)
insert into @test 
values
('6/20/2011 18:00'         ,  '5/16/2011'        ,  '17:13:17')
select Datediff(second,cast (date2 +' '+date3 as datetime),cast (date1 as datetime)) from @test
```

Comment: In my table all the datatypes are of Varchar(50) I tried your query too but it gives me the same error

Comment: @Peter I thought they where datetime, date and time respectively. That's what you put on your question: `How to get Time difference Between Datetime, Date and Time columns`. Casting to their respective types should work. Let me configm

Comment: my bad but i have put the datatypes in comments above

Comment: @peter added the version with all varchar types. That should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(DATETIME,Datesub + ' ' + TimeSub,101),CONVERT(DATETIME,DateTimeClosed,101))
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: @peter - Then you probably have a date that is on a different format that your example, or some impossible date (like '13/13/2011')

Comment: Thank you so much I just found there was a record which has value like 'Close' that's what causing the error. If i take out that your query is working perfectly. Thanks Once again

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

This example will return minutes:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(m, CONVERT(datetime, [Datesub] + ' ' + [TimeSub]), CONVERT(datetime, [DateTimeClosed]))
FROM dbo.Data_details
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY
;with dates AS 
(
SELECT '6/20/2011 18:00' as datetimeclosed,'5/16/2011' as datesub,'17:13:17' as timesub UNION ALL
SELECT '6/20/2011 18:00','5/18/2011','13:45:17' UNION ALL
SELECT '6/1/2011 19:00','5/24/2011','8:30:12' 
)
SELECT
DATEDIFF(minute,CAST(datesub + ' ' + timesub AS DATETIME),CAST(datetimeclosed AS DATETIME)) as time_diff_in_minutes
 FROM dates
```